# Best Way to Tranform XML to Specific XML or JSON Format in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, transformation

What's the best way to transform the XML to a specific XML Format or JSON Format ?

Which npm packages can be used ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd give [xml2js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml2js) a try, this makes XML to JSON conversion very easy:

```
const xml2js = require('xml2js');

function testXmlParse(xml) {
    const parser = new xml2js.Parser( { explicitArray: false })
    parser.parseString(xml, (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error("An error occurred: ", err);
        } else {
            console.log("Xml to Json result: ", result);
        }
    })
}

const xmlInput = "<note><to>Tove</to><from>Jani</from><heading>Reminder</heading><body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body></note>";
testXmlParse(xmlInput);
```

Here's an example of some Xml manipulation using [xmldom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xmldom):

```
const xmldom = require('xmldom');
const xpath = require('xpath');

var parser = new xmldom.DOMParser();
var serializer = new xmldom.XMLSerializer();

const xml = '<catalog><book id="bk101"><author>Gambardella, Matthew</author><title>XML Developer\'s Guide</title><genre>Computer</genre><price>44.95</price><publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date><description>An in-depth look at creating applicationswith XML.</description></book><book id="bk102"><author>Ralls, Kim</author><title>Midnight Rain</title><genre>Fantasy</genre><price>5.95</price><publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date><description>A former architect battles corporate zombies,an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queenof the world.</description></book><book id="bk103"><author>Corets, Eva</author><title>Maeve Ascendant</title><genre>Fantasy</genre><price>5.95</price><publish_date>2000-11-17</publish_date><description>After the collapse of a nanotechnologysociety in England, the young survivors lay thefoundation for a new society.</description></book><book id="bk104"><author>Corets, Eva</author><title>Oberon\'s Legacy</title><genre>Fantasy</genre><price>5.95</price><publish_date>2001-03-10</publish_date><description>In post-apocalypse England, the mysteriousagent known only as Oberon helps to create a new lifefor the inhabitants of London. Sequel to MaeveAscendant.</description></book><book id="bk105"><author>Corets, Eva</author><title>The Sundered Grail</title><genre>Fantasy</genre><price>5.95</price><publish_date>2001-09-10</publish_date><description>The two daughters of Maeve, half-sisters,battle one another for control of England. Sequel toOberon\'s Legacy.</description></book><book id="bk106"><author>Randall, Cynthia</author><title>Lover Birds</title><genre>Romance</genre><price>4.95</price><publish_date>2000-09-02</publish_date><description>When Carla meets Paul at an ornithologyconference, tempers fly as feathers get ruffled.</description></book><book id="bk107"><author>Thurman, Paula</author><title>Splish Splash</title><genre>Romance</genre><price>4.95</price><publish_date>2000-11-02</publish_date><description>A deep sea diver finds true love twentythousand leagues beneath the sea.</description></book><book id="bk108"><author>Knorr, Stefan</author><title>Creepy Crawlies</title><genre>Horror</genre><price>4.95</price><publish_date>2000-12-06</publish_date><description>An anthology of horror stories about roaches,centipedes, scorpionsand other insects.</description></book><book id="bk109"><author>Kress, Peter</author><title>Paradox Lost</title><genre>Science Fiction</genre><price>6.95</price><publish_date>2000-11-02</publish_date><description>After an inadvertant trip through a HeisenbergUncertainty Device, James Salway discovers the problemsof being quantum.</description></book><book id="bk110"><author>O\'Brien, Tim</author><title>Microsoft .NET: The Programming Bible</title><genre>Computer</genre><price>36.95</price><publish_date>2000-12-09</publish_date><description>Microsoft\'s .NET initiative is explored indetail in this deep programmer\'s reference.</description></book><book id="bk111"><author>O\'Brien, Tim</author><title>MSXML3: A Comprehensive Guide</title><genre>Computer</genre><price>36.95</price><publish_date>2000-12-01</publish_date><description>The Microsoft MSXML3 parser is covered indetail, with attention to XML DOM interfaces, XSLT processing,SAX and more.</description></book><book id="bk112"><author>Galos, Mike</author><title>Visual Studio 7: A Comprehensive Guide</title><genre>Computer</genre><price>49.95</price><publish_date>2001-04-16</publish_date><description>Microsoft Visual Studio 7 is explored in depth,looking at how Visual Basic, Visual C++, C#, and ASP+ areintegrated into a comprehensive developmentenvironment.</description></book></catalog>';

const root = parser.parseFromString(xml);
let selectedNodes = xpath.select('//book/author', root);

var newDoc = new xmldom.DOMParser().parseFromString("<test/>");
// Move nodes to new document..
selectedNodes.forEach(function (n) {
    newDoc.appendChild(n);
});

console.log("Processed Xml: ", serializer.serializeToString(newDoc));
```

Comment: my usecase is to get only the few attributes of XML from a bigger XML 
if 10 attributes are there in response XML , I just need 2 attributes according to my data model 

I want my bigger xml to be shortened to a smaller XML which later I can convert into JSON

Comment: In that case it should be easy enough to strip out what you need using maybe xmldom.. once this is done you can convert to JSON. I've updated giving an example of Xml manipulation using xmldom.

Comment: @techie i built camaro for that purpose. you can see the example on camaro readme page https://github.com/tuananh/camaro

Answer (score 0):

I build [camaro](https://github.com/tuananh/camaro) for that specific purpose, to extract and transform the xml input. You can see the below image to get an idea of how it works

basically, you write a xpath template specify what field you want, where is it (via xpath), how do you want to name it in json output

[image]